# Missing Expression

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have 2 tables one contain just the dates such as

table1: select display_date from dates; --will display the whole month dates(01-31)

```
____________________________
display_date
___________________

01-OCT-14
02-OCT-14
03-OCT-14
.....SO ON
```

---

table2: select display_date, weekday, day, month from employee_Day -- this contains some dates from month (01,04,05, etc..). it wont contain all the dates

```
______________________________________________
|display_date   |  weekday   | day  |  month  |
-----------------------------------------------
01-OCT-14          7           01       10
04-OCT-14          5           04       10
_______________________________________________
```

I need to join those two tables and i have to get the output of all the dates and null values for the records which i need the output like as shown below

```
_____________________________________________
display_date   |   weekday |  day   | month   |
_______________________________________________

01-OCT-14         7           01      10
02-OCT-14         5           02      10
03-OCT-14         4           03      10    



select a.display_date, b.weekday, b.day, b.month from (subquery1) a, (subquery2) b where TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(a.DISPLAY_DATE,'DD-MON-RR'),'DD')= TO_CHAR(b.DAY_NUMBER)(+);
```

subquery1: select  first table values

subquery2 : get secong table values

I am getting missing expression error .

I need to get common values in DISPLAY_DATE column if there is no value for display_date in table 2 then it has to join the result from table1. 
I cant use union because the columns on table 1 and 2 are different
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `left join`

```
SELECT d.display_date, e.weekday, e.day, e.month 
FROM Dates d
LEFT JOIN employee_Day e
ON d.display_date = e.display_date
```

Comment: Hey @RADAR i have one more question. How can i pass large string to stored procedure ?. when im using clob it is throwing identifier too long error

Comment: @user3707681, i am not sure of this question as i am new to oracle , probably need to ask as another question

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need something like this:

```
select a.display_date,
       nvl(b.weekday, to_char(a.display_date, 'D')) weekday,
       nvl(b.day, to_char(a.display_date, 'DD')) day,
       nvl(b.month, to_char(a.display_date, 'MM')) month
from table1 a left join table2 b on a.display_date = b.display_date
order by a.display_date;
```

Oracle recommends to avoid using of (+) as it's derpicated.

NVL(expr1, expr2) = if expr1 is null then expr2 else expr1